# Dataframe layout adaption - transposing, turning rows into column names and grouping by

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Python Pandas dataframe:

```
code   name  account_name value 
1      john  debt           123
1      john  revenue        432
1      john  growth           2
2      mark  cost           345
2      mark  debt           432
2      mark  revenue        432
2      mark  growth         456
```

I need it to look like this:

```
code   name  debt revenue  growth  cost   
1      john   123     432       2     
2      mark   432     432     456   345
```

I imagine it might be a combination of groupby's and transposes but I'm not getting it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) :

```
df.pivot_table(index=['name','code'],columns='account_name',values='value').rename_axis(None,1).reset_index()

   name  code   cost   debt  growth  revenue
0  john     1    NaN  123.0     2.0    432.0
1  mark     2  345.0  432.0   456.0    432.0
```